# Get textview value position wise in recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of mutliple item. in my list every item contains a status which can be 1 or 2. i have also two button one is confirm one is completed. Now i want to hide the complete button if the status is 2 and hide confirm button if the status is 1. But it only check the status of first item. Please help

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Fmb2borderadapter.orderfmholder holder, int position) {
    Fmordermodel fmordermodel = fmsarr.get(position);
    holder.assignOrderNbr.setText(fmordermodel.getAssignOrderno());
    holder.assignCustomerID.setText(fmordermodel.getOrder_unique_id());
    holder.assignOrderDate.setText(fmordermodel.getAssignOrderDate());
    holder.tv_status.setText(fmordermodel.getStatus());
    status = fmordermodel.getStatus();
    holder.tv_status.setTag(position);
    status = fmordermodel.getStatus();

   // holder.tv_status.setVisibility(holder.tv_status.getTag(position)=="2"?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);


    if (holder.tv_status.toString() ==  "2" ){
        holder.tv_complete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_confrim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        holder.tv_complete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tv_confrim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `if-block` as follows:

```
if (holder.tv_status.getText().toString().equals("2")) {
    //...
}
```

You have dropped `getText()` method. By the way, don't use `==` operator to compare `String` values unless you want to check the references. Use `equals()` instead to efficiently compare two `String` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
if (holder.tv_status.toString() ==  "2" ){
```

with this line

```
if (holder.tv_status.toString().equals("2" ){
```

Comment: There's a missing ")", sorry I'm not able to edit it

Comment: i tried but my issue is that it will not check the status of all items. now it is checking the status of only 1st item and the status of first item is 2 so it hide the completed button from all items but i want to hide only where the status is 2